# Set a Mock Object Property Then Verify It Is Used in Method Call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm attempting to create a test which verifies that a specific method is called. The method accepts two parameters, and I'd like to check that it gets called with that object having a specific property set.

Here's the code:

```
private void InitialiseContentTypes()
{
    IContentType blogContentTypeComposition = _blogContentTypeFactory.GetComposition();

    _umbracoContentTypeService.Save(blogContentTypeComposition);
}
```

This gets the composition from a factory, then uses it in the `Save` method. In the test, the `blogContentTypeComposition` should have a property called alias set to `aldusBlogComposition` (`blogContentTypeComposition.Alias`).

Here's the test code:

```
[Test]
[TestCase("aldusBlogComposition")]
public void Initialise_WhenCalled_SavesComposition(string alias)
{
    Mock<IContentType> contentType = new Mock<IContentType>();

    _blogContentTypeFactory
        .Setup(f => f.GetComposition())
        .Callback(() => { contentType.SetupProperty(ct => ct.Alias, alias); });

    _component.Initialize();

    _contentTypeService.Verify(s => s.Save(It.Is<IContentType>(ct => ct.Alias == alias), It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
}
```

This code creates a mock IContentType and when `GetComposition` is called, it sets the alias to `aldusBlogComposition`. Then the `Verify` should check that the `Save` method runs once, with the first parameter an IContentType with the alias property set to `aldusBlogComposition`.

When I run the test, this throws an error (below) which I suspect means that the mock isn't being used in the Verify method call.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

The error is being thrown as part of the `contentTypeService.Verify(s => s.Save(It.Is<IContentType>(ct => ct.Alias == alias), It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);` call. The only thing I can see being `null` is `ct` - if I swap this out for just `It.IsAny<IContentType>()` the error isn't thrown. I understand what a null reference is, but I don't understand why the parameter is null.

Full classes for reference:

Tests class:

```
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Components;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Factories.ContentTypes.Interfaces;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Services.Interfaces;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;

namespace Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Tests.Components
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ContentTypeComponentTests
    {
        private Mock<IContentTypeService> _contentTypeService;

        private Mock<IAldusContentTypeContainerService> _contentTypeContainerService;

        private Mock<IBlogContentTypeFactory> _blogContentTypeFactory;

        private ContentTypeComponent _component;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _contentTypeService = new Mock<IContentTypeService>();

            _contentTypeContainerService = new Mock<IAldusContentTypeContainerService>();

            _blogContentTypeFactory = new Mock<IBlogContentTypeFactory>();

            _component = new ContentTypeComponent(_contentTypeService.Object, _contentTypeContainerService.Object, _blogContentTypeFactory.Object);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Initialize_WhenCalled_GetAldusContainer()
        {
            _component.Initialize();

            _contentTypeContainerService.Verify(s => s.GetContainer("Aldus", 1, -1));
        }

        [Test]
        public void Initialise_AldusContainerExists_GetAldusCompositionContainer()
        {
            _contentTypeContainerService
                .Setup(s => s.GetContainer("Aldus", 1, -1))
                .Returns(new EntityContainer(Constants.ObjectTypes.DocumentType)
                {
                    Id = 1
                });

            _component.Initialize();

            _contentTypeContainerService.Verify(s => s.GetContainer("Aldus Compositions", 2, 1));
        }

        [Test]
        public void Initialise_AldusContainerDoesNotExist_DoNoGetAldusCompositionsContainer()
        {
            _contentTypeContainerService
                .Setup(s => s.GetContainer("Aldus", 1, -1))
                .Returns((EntityContainer) null);

            _component.Initialize();

            _contentTypeContainerService.Verify(s => s.GetContainer("Aldus Compositions", 2, It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Never());
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCase("aldusBlogComposition")]
        public void Initialise_WhenCalled_SavesComposition(string alias)
        {
            Mock<IContentType> contentType = new Mock<IContentType>();

            _blogContentTypeFactory
                .Setup(f => f.GetComposition())
                .Callback(() => { contentType.SetupProperty(ct => ct.Alias, alias); });

            _component.Initialize();

            _contentTypeService.Verify(s => s.Save(It.IsAny<IContentType>(), It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Initialise_WhenCalled_SavesBlogContentType()
        {
            Mock<IContentType> contentType = new Mock<IContentType>();

            contentType.SetupProperty(ct => ct.Alias, "aldus");

            _blogContentTypeFactory
                .Setup(f => f.GetContentType())
                .Returns(contentType.Object);

            _component.Initialize();

            _contentTypeService.Verify(s => s.Save(contentType.Object, It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
        }
    }
}
```

Component class:

```
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Factories.ContentTypes.Interfaces;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Services.Interfaces;
using Umbraco.Core.Composing;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;

namespace Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Components
{
    public class ContentTypeComponent : IComponent
    {
        private readonly IAldusContentTypeContainerService _contentTypeContainerService;

        private readonly IContentTypeService _umbracoContentTypeService;

        private EntityContainer _aldusContainer;

        private readonly IBlogContentTypeFactory _blogContentTypeFactory;

        public ContentTypeComponent(
            IContentTypeService umbracoContentTypeService,
            IAldusContentTypeContainerService contentTypeContainerService,
            IBlogContentTypeFactory blogContentTypeFactory)
        {
            _umbracoContentTypeService = umbracoContentTypeService;

            _contentTypeContainerService = contentTypeContainerService;

            _blogContentTypeFactory = blogContentTypeFactory;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            InitialiseContainers();
            InitialiseContentTypes();
        }

        private void InitialiseContainers()
        {
            _aldusContainer = _contentTypeContainerService.GetContainer("Aldus", 1);

            if (_aldusContainer != null)
            {
                _contentTypeContainerService.GetContainer("Aldus Compositions", 2, _aldusContainer.Id);
            }
        }

        private void InitialiseContentTypes()
        {
            IContentType blogContentTypeComposition = _blogContentTypeFactory.GetComposition();

            _umbracoContentTypeService.Save(blogContentTypeComposition);

            IContentType blogContentType = _blogContentTypeFactory.GetContentType();

            _umbracoContentTypeService.Save(blogContentType);
        }

        public void Terminate() { }
    }
}
```

And the blog factory class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Factories.ContentTypes.Interfaces;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Utils.Services.Interfaces;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;

namespace Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Factories.ContentTypes
{
    public class BlogContentTypeFactory : ContentTypeFactory, IBlogContentTypeFactory
    {
        public BlogContentTypeFactory(
            IContentTypeService contentTypeService,
            IPapermoonContentTypeService papermoonContentTypeService,
            IPapermoonContentTypeContainerService papermoonContentTypeContainerService,
            IPapermoonTemplateService papermoonTemplateService)
            : base(
                contentTypeService,
                papermoonContentTypeService,
                papermoonContentTypeContainerService,
                papermoonTemplateService) { }

        public IContentType GetComposition()
        {
            Composition = ContentTypeService.Get("aldusBlogComposition");

            if (Composition == null)
            {
                Composition = new ContentType(AldusCompositionsContainer.Id);
            }

            Composition.Name = "Aldus Blog Composition";
            Composition.Alias = "aldusBlogComposition";
            Composition.Description = "A composition for the Aldus blog listing.";
            Composition.Icon = "icon-settings";

            return Composition;
        }

        public IContentType GetContentType()
        {
            ContentType = ContentTypeService.Get("aldusBlog");

            if (ContentType == null)
            {
                ContentType = new ContentType(AldusContainer.Id);
            }

            ContentType.Name = "Blog";
            ContentType.Alias = "aldusBlog";
            ContentType.Description = "Aldus blog listing.";
            ContentType.Icon = "icon-article";

            ContentType.AllowedTemplates = PapermoonTemplateService.Get(new [] { "AldusBlog" });

            ContentType.SetDefaultTemplate(ContentType.AllowedTemplates.First());

            ContentType.ContentTypeComposition =
                PapermoonContentTypeService.GetCompositions(ContentType, new List<string> {"aldusBlogComposition"});

            return ContentType;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the content type factory class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Factories.ContentTypes.Interfaces;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Utils.Services.Interfaces;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;

namespace Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Factories.ContentTypes
{
    public class BlogContentTypeFactory : ContentTypeFactory, IBlogContentTypeFactory
    {
        public BlogContentTypeFactory(
            IContentTypeService contentTypeService,
            IPapermoonContentTypeService papermoonContentTypeService,
            IPapermoonContentTypeContainerService papermoonContentTypeContainerService,
            IPapermoonTemplateService papermoonTemplateService)
            : base(
                contentTypeService,
                papermoonContentTypeService,
                papermoonContentTypeContainerService,
                papermoonTemplateService) { }

        public IContentType GetComposition()
        {
            Composition = ContentTypeService.Get("aldusBlogComposition");

            if (Composition == null)
            {
                Composition = new ContentType(AldusCompositionsContainer.Id);
            }

            Composition.Name = "Aldus Blog Composition";
            Composition.Alias = "aldusBlogComposition";
            Composition.Description = "A composition for the Aldus blog listing.";
            Composition.Icon = "icon-settings";

            return Composition;
        }

        public IContentType GetContentType()
        {
            ContentType = ContentTypeService.Get("aldusBlog");

            if (ContentType == null)
            {
                ContentType = new ContentType(AldusContainer.Id);
            }

            ContentType.Name = "Blog";
            ContentType.Alias = "aldusBlog";
            ContentType.Description = "Aldus blog listing.";
            ContentType.Icon = "icon-article";

            ContentType.AllowedTemplates = PapermoonTemplateService.Get(new [] { "AldusBlog" });

            ContentType.SetDefaultTemplate(ContentType.AllowedTemplates.First());

            ContentType.ContentTypeComposition =
                PapermoonContentTypeService.GetCompositions(ContentType, new List<string> {"aldusBlogComposition"});

            return ContentType;
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I've tried adding a call to `.Returns` but still see the error. I've tried the following ways:

After the callback:

```
_blogContentTypeFactory
    .Setup(f => f.GetComposition())
    .Callback(() => { contentType.SetupProperty(ct => ct.Alias == alias); })
    .Returns(contentType.Object);
```

Assignment as part of the return:

```
_blogContentTypeFactory
    .Setup(f => f.GetComposition())
    .Returns(contentType.SetupProperty(ct => ct.Alias, alias).Object);
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and see where the Null Reference is? Are you passing the Mocked services and factory into the concrete class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because you are missing the `.Returns` usage on the `Mock` factory instead?

```cs
    contentType.SetupProperty(ct => ct.Alias, alias)

   _blogContentTypeFactory
        .Setup(f => f.GetComposition())
        .Returns(contentType.SetupProperty);
```

Hard to tell without seeing more code around the instantiation of the concrete class.

Comment: I've tried adding `.Returns` in a couple of ways, could 100% be doing it wrong! Updated the question with info.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to configure the mock and its property.

The following uses the [LINQ to Mocks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#linq-to-mocks) appraoch

```
[Test]
[TestCase("aldusBlogComposition")]
public void Initialise_WhenCalled_SavesComposition(string alias) {
    //Arrange
    IContentType contentType = Mock.Of<IContentType>(_ => _.ALias == alias);

    _blogContentTypeFactory
        .Setup(_ => _.GetComposition())
        .Returns(contentType);

    //Act
    _component.Initialize();

    //Assert
    _contentTypeService.Verify(s => s.Save(It.Is<IContentType>(ct => ct.Alias == alias), It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
}
```

You could have even verified that it was the same returned instance that was passed

```
//...omitted for brevity

//Assert
_contentTypeService.Verify(s => s.Save(contentType, It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `Verify` set up was right but a null value was being returned from the `GetContentType` method, I just need to set up a return:

```
_blogContentTypeFactory
    .Setup(f => f.GetContentType())
    .Returns(Mock.Of<IContentType>());
```

Comment: it looks like my answer was literally what you used? Please could you accept that?